I'm building an app in Vendure, trying out the requestPasswordReset API call, I get a response saying success, but nothing get's triggered, why?
I'm new to Vendure and I'm trying out it's core functionalities.
I implemented the login, registerCustomerAccount methods successfully, but I ran into an annoying issue, that I need help with.
There is a GraphQL mutation called requestPasswordReset which does work with Postman and triggers all the Vendure events that should be triggered, creates a new passwordResetToken in the database and generates an Email.
But whenever I try to call that endpoint from my web app I get a response saying success, but nothing happens on the backend, nothing gets triggered, no email generation is happening, the passwordResetToken field in the database stays empty. Why is that?
Here is my implementation of the mutation.
//storefront-remix-starter/app/providers/account/account.ts


export const requestPasswordReset = async(
  input: { emailAddress: string; },
  options: QueryOptions,
): Promise<RequestPasswordResetMutation['requestPasswordReset']> => {
  return sdk.requestPasswordReset(input, options).then((res) => res.requestPasswordReset);
};

gql`
  mutation requestPasswordReset(
    $emailAddress: String!
) {
    requestPasswordReset(
        emailAddress: $emailAddress
    ) {
        __typename
        ... on NativeAuthStrategyError {
            errorCode
            message
        }
        ... on Success {
            success
        }
    }
}
`;

Of course, I ran yarn generate to have RequestPasswordResetMutation recognized.
Here is the action method that I tried.
//storefront-remix-starter/app/routes/api/user/forgot-password.tsx

import { ActionFunctionArgs, json, redirect } from "@remix-run/server-runtime";
import { requestPasswordReset } from "~/providers/account/account";
import { EMAIL_REGEX } from "~/utils/registration-helper";

export async function action({ params, request }: ActionFunctionArgs) {
  const body = await request.formData();
  const email = body.get('email');
  
  if (!email || typeof email !== 'string' || !email.match(EMAIL_REGEX)) {
    const formError = { form: "Invalid email address" };
    return json(formError, { status: 400 });
  }

    const result = await requestPasswordReset({ emailAddress: email }, { request });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result) {
      const formError = { form: "No response from the server" };
      return json(formError, { status: 500 });
    }

    if (result.__typename === 'Success') {
      return redirect('/success');
    } else {
      const formError = { form: result.message || "An error occurred" };
      return json(formError, { status: 401 });
    }
}

And here is the form on which I try to call this action method.
//storefront-remix-starter/app/components/form/PasswordForm.tsx

import { Button } from "../ui-custom/MyButton";
import { Input } from "../ui-custom/MyInput";
import { Label } from "../ui/label";
import { Form } from "@remix-run/react";

const PasswordForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form method='post' action='api/user/forgot-password' className='flex flex-col gap-6'>
      <div className='grid w-full items-center'>
        <Label className='mb-1.5' htmlFor='email-address'>
          Email address
        </Label>
        <Input name='email' type='text' id='email-address' />
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col gap-4'>
        <Button type="submit">Request new password</Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default PasswordForm;

I logged everything form the beginning to the end, and it seems like that everything is going well, the request gets sent, with the proper values, as I said I even get back a response, saying { __typename: 'Success', success: true }
Any input on the issue would be a great help!
Thank you!
I tried to log everything, got no issue that would lead me to the core of the case
